# Ray Tune ; combine population based training schedule with Hyperopt

Tags: performance, hyperparameters, ray, hyperopt

Are Population Based Training (PBT) and HyperOpt Search combinable ?

The AsyncHyperBandScheduler is used in the [Hyperopt Example](https://github.com/ray-project/ray/blob/master/python/ray/tune/examples/hyperopt_example.py) of `ray.tune`

Here config set some parameters for the `run()` function

```
config = {
    "num_samples": 10 if args.smoke_test else 1000,
    "config": {
        "iterations": 100,
    },
    "stop": {
        "timesteps_total": 100
    },
}
```

and space is the argument for the hyperparameter Space inside the [Tune Search Algorithm](https://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tune-searchalg.html) with `hyperopt` functions:

```
space = {
    "width": hp.uniform("width", 0, 20),
    "height": hp.uniform("height", -100, 100),
    "activation": hp.choice("activation", ["relu", "tanh"])
}

algo = HyperOptSearch()
scheduler = AsyncHyperBandScheduler()
run(easy_objective, search_alg=algo, scheduler=scheduler, **config)
```

yet in the [population-based example with Keras](https://github.com/ray-project/ray/blob/master/python/ray/tune/examples/pbt_memnn_example.py) the hyperparameter space is loosely given by `hyperparam_mutations` inside the [Tune Trials Scheduler](https://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tune-schedulers.html#population-based-training-pbt) with `numpy` functions

```
pbt = PopulationBasedTraining(
    hyperparam_mutations={
        "dropout": lambda: np.random.uniform(0, 1),
        "lr": lambda: 10**np.random.randint(-10, 0),
        "rho": lambda: np.random.uniform(0, 1)
    })
```

and config is used in a different way:

To set starting parameters for individuals of the population

```
run(MemNNModel,scheduler=pbt,
     config={
        "batch_size": 32,
        "epochs": 1,
        "dropout": 0.3,
        "lr": 0.01,
        "rho": 0.9
    })
```

To summarize:

Hyperopt takes its the Hyperparameter Space inside the Search Algorithm with `hyperopt` functions
Population-Based Training takes its the Hyperparameter Space inside the Trials Scheduler with `numpy` functions
Both use Config differently

From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57513830/9447180) I take that, the Hyperopt Search will only take completed Trials into account.

Is there a conflict with sampled hyperparameters from Hyperopt Search and "changed while running" hyperparameters from Population-Based Training? 
quote: "a single trial may see many different hyperparameters over its lifetime"